# Cisco packet tracer

Tags: networking, cisco

I'm beginner at networking, I notice that after configuring a network when I try to test the network connectivity with sending msg every time at the first attempt It always says "Failed" and then it says "successful" . what is the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you try to ping the device, the first packet will fail. that time it will initiate the packet for the first time.

1). your MAC address table does not have destination Addresses.
2). Routing entry will not there.

after finding the destination of the device it will flow the packet without failure.

Comment: As a heads-up, this question is likely to be closed due to it being off-topic (that is, not about programming).